# How do i manipulate the data inside of a factory in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, factory

Im attempting to set some data inside of a factory, and expose some methods to get and set said data. But, I am not getting why it doesn't work. Here is the code 
http://plnkr.co/edit/dFCEQ9QIRjitEAQz7HnW?p=preview

looking for a better understanding of the factory use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error in the code. `setD()` is not accessible, it should be `setData()`.

```
app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, Data) {
  Data.setData();
  $scope.data = Data.getData();
});
```